# Expressions reducible to factorial form

Tags: factorial

Can the following expression be written as the factorial of $m$?

$m(m-1)(m-2) \dots {m-(n-1)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$m(m-1)\cdots (m-n+1) = \frac{m(m-1)\cdots (m-n+1)(m-n)!}{(m-n)!} = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can write $$m(m-1)(m-2) \dots {m-(n-1)}=\frac {m!}{(m-n)!}$$
Note which factors are missing from $m!$ in your original expression

Comment: @Bladewood:  the last factor on the left is $m-n+1$.  The first factor in the denominator is $m-n$, which is the next one after $m-n+1$, so this is right.  There is also something wrong with your MathJax, I think a dollar sign is missing.

Comment: You're right, my mortal eyes were messing with me. Re MathJax, I think the !s are messing with the $s.

Comment: @Bladewood:  It looked like you were escaping the !s with backslashes.  They don't need them.  Maybe you escaped a dollar sign by mistake.